# Array Entry Removal Causing an Access Violation Error

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been working on an assignment for university the past few hours and I am pretty much finished save for one error. I managed to track down the error to a loop inside this function. The function is supposed to remove a desired entry from the call_DB array, then shift the following entries up one index number, then subtract the count by one so that no empty space is left in the array which is later printed into a text file. That function is here:

```
void remove_DB(call_record call_DB[], int & count, string cell_number)
{

   int location = search_DB(call_DB, count, cell_number);

   while (location != -1)
   {
        location = search_DB(call_DB, count, cell_number);

        if (location != -1)
        {
          for (int i = location; i < count; i++)
          {
            call_DB[i] = call_DB[i + 1];
          }

          count--;
        }

   }
 }
```

In case it is relevant the search function looks through a user defined class array (sorry if that is the wrong terminology) and returns the index 'i' of the location for the searched entry. It returns a -1 if nothing is found. That code is here:

```
int search_DB(call_record call_DB[], int count, string cell_number)
{

 int i;

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {

      if (call_DB[i].cell_num == cell_number)
      {
        return i;
      }
      return -1;
   }

}
```

Specifically, the error occurs after the for loop exits when it hits the 'count - -;' statement inside remove_DB. The last time the loop executes before the error the value for call_DB[i +1] becomes:

> "call_DB[i+1]  {cell_num= relays=1 minutes=7116664 ...}"

according to the value monitor in Visual Studio. If the code proceeds after this iteration a pop-up error which displays the message:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x0F6131CA (msvcr120d.dll) in my_program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x68FD7339."

Followed by a tab opening in Visual Studio which tells me memcpy.asm is not found.

I hope this isn't something obvious I'm not seeing but I'm really stumped here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `count` is the number of records in `call_DB`, there's a pretty obvious bug here

Comment: What are you passing as `call_DB[]` into these functions, how is it defined/allocated, and how are you making sure you don't overflow its bounds?

Comment: `mething obvious I'm not seeing but I'm really stumped here`  Why don't you use the debugger that comes with Visual Studio?  You have an obvious bug in that loop that searches for a cell_number.

Comment: A question about your implementation -- What happens if you tried to delete only the last entry (forgetting about the current error)?  What do you replace the last entry with, since there is no "DB[last+1]" entry to overwrite "DB[last]"?  You need to show us exactly how DB is declared, and whether you are assuming there is no "last entry", but instead some sort of sentinel value.

Comment: Pass string by const reference.

Comment: @uesp call_DB[] is an array of the class, call_record, which contains string cell_num, int relays, int minutes, double net_cost, double tax_rate, double call_tax, and double total_cost. The array is of the size capacity which is a global variable that is equal to 20. As for how I'm making sure I'm not overflowing the bounds? I don't know, I've learnt this stuff recently and don't know the ins and outs yet.

Comment: @mooo90 - You have to be careful about the indexing, that's all.  Even a professional can make a mistake like this (not often, but can happen).

Comment: @mooo90 - I would declare your DB array as 21 entries, with the last entry serving as a dummy item, and rely on `count` to tell me how many items are actually valid.  This way, the fixes I suggested below in the answer should work.  However, when you discover `std::vector`, all of this becomes moot since erasing entries in a `vector` are a piece of cake.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the help. I implemented everything you suggested and it resolved the those errors. Only thing is I'm now receiving the error:

"Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i == `count-1`, and DB is an array that has `count` entries, then `DB[i + 1]` is out of bounds:

```
for (int i = location; i < count; i++)
{
  call_DB[i] = call_DB[i + 1];
}
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = location; i < count-1; i++)
  call_DB[i] = call_DB[i + 1];
```

Second, your loop that searches is wrong.  If the item isn't at position 0 in the array, you will always return -1.

It should be:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
        if (call_DB[i].cell_num == cell_number)
        return i;
   }
   return -1;
```

But you have another issue, and that is you'll have trouble deleting the last item in DB if DB consists of purely data, and not a dummy or sentinel value at the end of the array.  The easiest fix for that would be to declare your array 1 entry larger than what you expect, and have the last entry serve as a dummy value.

Comment: Paul, it will take com convincing for me to believe you did *not* have it wright the first time. `count` of *anything* is zero-based. Either there are none (count=0), one (count=1), etc. And since native arrays are always 0-based indexed in C/C++... you had it right, and have my up-tick. Right now its offsetting someone else's down-tick for some reason.

Comment: The 1-baseness is taken care of by subtracting 1.  I know it gets confusing sometimes.  @WhozCraig -- you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you need to do, is find the index of the data you want to remove and move everything below that one slot up, thus overwriting the data you want to delete.

```
void remove_DB(call_record call_DB[], int & count, string cell_number)
{

   int location = search_DB(call_DB, count, cell_number);

   if (location < 0)
      return;

   for (location; location < count - 1; location++)
   {
       call_DB[location] = call_DB[location+1];
   }
   count--;
   return;
}
```